# how to generate .wsdl from java code

Tags: java, eclipse, wsdl

How to generate WSDL from a class file using eclipse Axis2 Codegen Wizard?

The steps I followed to do it:

-Create a basic class, with it's interface(Simple type with no dependance)
-right click in eclipse with axis2 codegen on the class.
-Fully qualified the class name my_package.class_name
-Adding folder(terminal folder of the package, here for example my_package)

-Test:

**java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my_package.class_name not found**.
(Even when I try from command line I get a classNotFound error)

I have tried a thousand time with different files package. I cannot make it work...
Even with explorer I am sure the .class file is well pl aced, and good folder added.

Can you provide me an example of how generate .wsdl **from .class** command line or in eclipse with **small file example, and all the step followed**.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Apache CXF tool "java2wsdl" may help you.

Here's the link : https://cxf.apache.org/docs/java-to-wsdl.html

Comment: Already using it, Still classNotFound, it is the only way using cmd.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found my mistakes:

- First I found that the path of Axis in eclipse wasn't set.
- And by cmd I found that I tried to give .java rather than compiled .class